# Jquery click anchor inside div distinguish both them

Tags: jquery, html, click, anchor

My issue is how to distinguish a clicked anchor and a clicked div where this anchor is inside a div.

```
<div class='box'>Message goes here and this is my anchor <a href="#"> my link</a></div>
<div class='output'></div>



 $(".box").click(function(){
       $('.output').append('box clicked!'); 
    });

    $(".box > a").click(function(){
        $('.output').append('anchor clicked!'); 
    });
```

so, i want get "anchor clicked" without having "box clicked". Is this possible?
take a look on this jsfiddle to understand my doubt: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x7bmn/)

Comment: You need to `stopPropagation` on the anchor click handler

Answer (score 4):

```
$(".box > a").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.output').append('anchor clicked!'); 
});
```

`.stopPropagation()` prevents your event from bubbling up through the DOM.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x7bmn/3/)

Answer (score 2):

When an event happens it goes up thru the DOM. You have to stop propagation :

```
event.stopPropagation()
```

Answer (score 1):

Working Fiddle `-->`  http://jsfiddle.net/x7bmn/2/

Use `event.stopPropagation();` to stop it from bubbling  up to the `div`

```
$(".box").click(function(){
       $('.output').append('box clicked!'); 
});

$(".box > a").click(function(event){
     event.stopPropagation();
     $('.output').append('anchor clicked!'); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

http://jsfiddle.net/x7bmn/1/

```
$(".box > a").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.output').append('anchor clicked!'); 
    // goal:applies B without applying A
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found another approach that it is more useful for my application. Using `event.target`.

Here is my sollution:

```
$(".box").click(function(e){
    if($(e.target).is('a'))
   $('.output').append('anchor clicked!');
   // only applies B
    else
        $('.output').append('box clicked!');
    // applies A
});
```

Thanks for your prompt answers.

Take a look on my [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FtpYs/)

Comment: This will work, too, but your click will still bubble up the DOM, fwiw.